# Getting blank notification in some Android device

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

In some device, I am getting a blank(white) notification like attached screenshot. And in some devices, it's working fine. Please help me to resolve this issue. 
 [image]

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
            builder.setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            // Sets the small icon for the ticker
            builder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon());
            builder.setLargeIcon(result);
            builder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentText(messageBody);
            builder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            RemoteViews expandedView =
                    new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
            {
                // Inflate and set the layout for the expanded notification view
                expandedView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imgBigImage, result);
                notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), notification);
            } else {
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                        .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                        .setLargeIcon(result)
                        .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), notificationBuilder.build());
            }
```

Comment: Lolipop and above version you are getting the issue. Isn't it ?

Comment: Add your notification code here..

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: @NilamVaddoriya i have added code. please review it

Comment: @AnkitaGuna What is the android version of that device in which blank notification comes?

Comment: @NitinPatel I have checked it in Lenovo P2 (7.0). and same thing i am getting in 6.0.1 version also. But not in all device having 6.0.1. and facing this same issue.

Comment: You need to make one white icon(which part you want to highlight) for lollipop and above version. Below lollipop you need to make transparent icon.

Comment: @Piyush icon is already implemented. But I think expandable view create an issue in some devices.

Comment: @AnkitaGuna Hu aa j use karu chu ne badha device ma proper chale che. Kai issue nthi avto

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to `setBigContentView` to `NotificationCompat.Builder` ,check if it works :-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
//        Notification notification = builder.build();
        RemoteViews expandedView =
                new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
        {
            builder.setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            // Sets the small icon for the ticker
            builder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon());
            builder.setLargeIcon(result);
            builder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentText(messageBody);
            builder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            // Inflate and set the layout for the expanded notification view
            expandedView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imgBigImage, result);
//            notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
            builder.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);
        } else {
            builder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon());
            builder.setLargeIcon(result);
            builder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentText(messageBody);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            builder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        }
        nm.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), builder.build());
```

Comment: @AnkitaGuna Now issue may be with `expandedView`. So first comment `builder.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);` line and try it to check.

Comment: @AnkitaGuna OK. then find and properly set `RemoteViews` will solve your problem.

Comment: @NitinPatel It works for me when I comment that line, but why?